# FileProvider: Installing APK. There was an error parsing the package

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to install apk after it has been downloaded by the download manager. I am using a broadcast to get the message after download completes. This is my code below:- 
FileProvider: Installing APK. There was an error parsing the package.

```
val file = File(getExternalFilesDir("Download"), "/playlist/update.apk")
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    val apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@MainActivity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
                    intent.data = apkUri
                    intent.flags= Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    this@MainActivity.startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    val apkUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    this@MainActivity.startActivity(intent)
                }
```

Manifest:-

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
```

filespath.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="Download" path="Download/" />
</paths>
```

I am downloading the apk in "Downloads/playlist/" dir. I saw this same problem - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217914/fileprovider-installing-apk-there-was-an-error-parsing-the-package). However I have can't seem to get it working from that solution. I also checked the apk by installing it myself and it gets installed without any errors. Please help.

Comment: Is the APK you're downloading actually compatible with your device?

Comment: Yes, it is. I can install it without any errors if I open the downloaded apk from storage.

Comment: OK, so do this. I'm guessing you have access to a computer with ADB, since you're developing an app: `adb shell` then `pm install -r /sdcard/Download/playlist/apkName.apk`. You'll have to fix that path, obviously. It should return a more detailed error.

Comment: It returned "Success"

Comment: That's interesting. It means there's something wrong with how you're starting the install process from the app.

Comment: Can you show how 'file' is defined?

Comment: Edited the code with how file is defined.

Comment: Well according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) I don't think you're using `getExternalFilesDir()` correctly. Try replacing that call with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); `.

Comment: The app craches. Error:- Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Download/playlist/update.apk

Comment: I need to duck out of this one then, sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for trying

Comment: @AyushSingh Did you find the cause and solution for this parsing error?

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same problem, did you ever get it done?

Comment: Nevermind, the function I was using to save the apk was not appending a slash thus screwing the uri. Too bad it is so hard to backtrack.